# How to groupBy length of Strings on a collection of Strings?

Tags: scala

I have a `Seq` of Strings.

```scala
val words = Seq("sad", "dsvc", "bbvv", "sf")
```

I'd like to use `groupBy` to get a map where the key is the length of the string and value is a collection of strings of that length.

```scala
val output = Map(3 -> ("sad"), 4 -> ("dsvc","bbvv"), 2 -> ("sf"))
```

Still rather new to Scala so I can't quite figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? - Writing this lambda is **Scala** 101, any tutorial / course / book should have prepared you to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [signature of `groupBy` on Seq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#groupBy%5BK%5D(f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BK,C%5D):

```scala
def groupBy[K](f: (A) => K): immutable.Map[K, Seq[A]]
```

You have a `Seq[String]` so you know `A=String`. The method is asking you to provide an answer to "group by *what*?" in the form of the function `f`, which gets that grouping criteria (of type `K`) from a given value of type `A` (i.e. your String). In your post you said you want to group by the string length, so `K` is the length type, i.e. Int. You just need to pass a function that returns the length of the given string. Constructing this function is the "lambda" that Luis referred to in his comment. Once you pass that function to `groupBy`, you get an `immutable.Map[K, Seq[A]]`, i.e. a Map whose keys are the string length (K) and whose values are Sequences of strings (Seq[A]) matching that length.

There are a couple different syntaxes for constructing anonymous functions (lambdas): one where you use `_` to represent the argument(s) of the function, and another where you make it look similar to a `def` method definition. E.g.
`_.length` or `s => s.length` would work.

```scala
val words = Seq("sad", "dsvc", "bbvv", "sf")

words.groupBy(_.length)
// val res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[String]] = 
//    HashMap(2 -> List(sf), 3 -> List(sad), 4 -> List(dsvc, bbvv))

// you could also return something other than the actual length
words.groupBy(s => s.length + 10)
// val res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[String]] = 
//    HashMap(14 -> List(dsvc, bbvv), 13 -> List(sad), 12 -> List(sf))
```